# Checking for differences in multiple records without primary keys

Tags: t-sql, duplicates, primary-key, normalization

My table structure is roughly as follows (there are more columns I'm leaving out)

```
WEAPON    MUNITION    RANGE
```

I'm writing a query to check a single table with many WEAPON-MUNITION pairings with different ranges. I need to find every instance a WEAPON-MUNITION has a different range. Duplicates are allowed because there are multiple data sets in this table. Yes it violates normalization but I didn't make it I just have to query it.

So say I have four weapon-munition parings with different ranges I need to be able to display them so they can be corrected. I've tried some complex CTE's and really convoluted self joins but when I think I have a result I can't tie it back to the original table because the column I thought was a primary key has duplicates between data sets! I need to display the whole record after finding the records described above. I end up with almost 10 times the rows I started with and I can't figure out why.

Short of asking the DBA to allow me to generate unique keys for every record I don't know how I can accomplish this.

***EDIT***
Using gregmac's example I came up with this query (generic and leaving out some columns and any proprietary info)

```
WITH range_cte AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        d1.WEAPON
       ,d1.MUNITION
       ,d1.WEAPON
       ,d1.RANGE
       ,d1.ID    --This is NOT a primary key! There are duplicates
    FROM data1 d1 INNER JOIN data2 d2
        ON  d1.WEAPON = d2.WEAPON
        AND d1.MUNITION = d2.MUNITION
        AND d1.RANGE <> d2.RANGE
    GROUP BY 
        d1.WEAPON
       ,d1.MUNITION
       ,d1.WEAPON
       ,d1.RANGE
       ,d1.ID
    ORDER BY 
        d1.WEAPON
       ,d1.MUNITION
)
--Self join the CTE on the original table using the ID (that's not a primary key)
SELECT * FROM range_cte r INNER JOIN data d
    ON r.ID = d.ID
```

My idea is to insert an auto generated key for the whole table or should I include more columns in the CTE (like data set) to form some sort of natural key?

Comment: Perhaps if you include a query you've tried, along with a description if what's wrong with the results, we could have a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'll need to check with my supervisor. All the code I write is automatically FOUO (For Official Use Only). I could lose my job if I make a mistake and post something public that I should not.

I will try to come up with a generic example of what I have already written and run it by the boss.

Comment: I added an example. I hope this helps clarify why I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you need to simply self-join, and find other rows where the weapon and munition are the same but the range is different.

I came up with this:

```
SELECT d1.* 
FROM data d1
INNER JOIN data d2 
  ON d1.weapon = d2.weapon 
    AND d1.munition = d2.munition 
    AND d1.range <> d2.range
GROUP BY d1.weapon, d1.munition, d1.range -- eliminate duplicates which are caused by joining both ways 
         ,d1.other1 ,d1.other2
ORDER BY d1.weapon, d1.munition
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  WEAPON    varchar(20), 
  MUNITION  varchar(20), 
  RANGE     varchar(20),
  other1    varchar(20),
  other2    varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO data VALUES ('a', 'x', '1', 'aaa','aaa');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('a', 'x', '2', 'aaa','bbb');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('a', 'y', '3', 'aaa','bbb');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('a', 'z', '4', 'ccc','ddd');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('b', 'x', '5', 'def','ghh');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('b', 'z', '6', 'ccc','ddd');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('b', 'z', '7', 'aaa','aaa');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('b', 'z', '8', 'aaa','bbb');
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('b', 'z', '9', 'aaa','ccc');
```

and output:

```
WEAPON  MUNITION  RANGE  other1  other2
a       x         1      aaa     aaa 
a       x         2      aaa     bbb 
b       z         6      ccc     ddd 
b       z         7      aaa     aaa 
b       z         8      aaa     bbb 
b       z         9      aaa     ccc
```

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65590/3/0

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar Query but I was missing the Group By clause that eliminated duplicates caused by the join! I'll give this a shot!

Comment: @OpsResearch36 I guess I am unclear.. What are you still asking that my answer doesn't answer?

Comment: Taking the output from the query and retrieving the full record from the original table where the distances are not the same.

Comment: @OpsResearch36 Basically you just need to add to the GROUP BY clause. Since the Range column is always guaranteed to be different, it won't mistakenly group rows where the other columns all match. I didn't realize, but SQLite allows the query without adding to the GROUP BY. I updated the example to show MSSQL syntax, "other" columns, and also changed the sqlfiddle to use the MSSQL engine.

Comment: Thank you this works! I accepted your answer but I cannot up-vote it since I don't have 15 rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: create a new table with all of the weapons-munitions pairs and the correct ranges.  Update the original table based on the values in the new table.

```
UPDATE o
SET o.range = n.range
FROM original AS o
JOIN new AS n ON o.weapon = n.weapon
    AND o.munition = n.munition
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure from the description, but perhaps you want something like this (the "mytable" cte is just my attempt to generate test data for your table, including an "othercolumn" but there could be more):

```
WITH mytable AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
    VALUES('w1','m1',10, 'o1'), ('w1','m1',20, 'o2'), 
           ('w2','m2',10, 'o3'),
           ('w3','m3',10, 'o4'), ('w3','m3',20,'o5'), ('w3','m3',30,'o6')
    )x(weapon,munition,[range], othercolumn)
), MultiRange AS (
SELECT weapon, munition FROM mytable
GROUP BY weapon,munition
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [range])>1
)
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
JOIN MultiRange m ON m.weapon = t.weapon AND m.munition = t.munition
ORDER BY weapon, munition, [range]
```

Comment: I'm building a query to do quality checks on a table already in the database. We get data from an external source. It is loaded through our VB.NET front end into various databases. This data feeds into a simulation and the users are having to manually check ranges to ensure a match. A tedious and time consuming task. This check should be done before it is even loaded for processing.